# How to integrate Solr and CakePhp3 using Solarium or any other clients?

Tags: mysql, solr, cakephp-3.0, solarium

I've developed an application on cakephp 3 which has a approximately 10 million rows in its database and expected to grow gradually. With MySQL search, it was too slow therefore **I've implemented Solr5** now I'm not getting how do I integrate Solr5 with my CakePhP Application's Search.

I've read that Solarium Client can help me do that or if there is any other client that can help integrating, please guide the steps. I'm flexible to use different clients which can help me resolve the issue.

If you have any specific documentation explaining the procedure, please share I'll be grateful to you.

Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Elastic Search? It is more "natively supported" by Cake3 http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html

Comment: 1) the OP asked specifically abut Solr, not Elastic. 2) the question itself is off-topic, asking for documentation / generic help (without showing a specific, objective issue that can be tackled here).